# CakePHP 2.3 Plugin doesn't seem to extend appcontroller

Tags: cakephp, authentication, plugins, cakephp-2.3

I've created a plugin called 'IssueTracker', which is located in `app/Plugin/IssueTracker`. I've created a Controller called `Tickets` and it is accessible at `www.example.com/issue_tracker/tickets/`. But, only for logged in users with the rank 'Admin'.

That wasn't exactly what I was hoping for, so I added in my `Plugin/IssueTracker/Controller/TicketsController.php` the following:

```php
public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
$this->Auth->allow('index');
}
```

I hoped that with this piece of code (which I'm using in several other controllers in my `app/Controller/` that it would inherit from my `AppController.php` file. The `TicketsController.php` file extends the `IssueTrackerAppController` (like this):

```
class TicketsController extends IssueTrackerAppController { 
//functions goes in here
}
```

And in my `Plugin/Controller` folder I've created the file `IssueTrackerAppController` which extends the `AppController`.

In my `AppController.php` file I've allready defined that `'index'` and `'view'` are public actions. But, for some reason, it doesn't work in my plugin.

Is there something that I'm overseeing? When I access `www.example.com/issue_tracker/tickets` as a not logged in user (Guest), it tells me that I need to login. If I'm logged in as a user, but not as an Admin, the `Auth` component won't allow me in and presents the login form.

There should be a way to get `Auth` working in a plugin, right?

**EDIT**

Below is the `AppController.php` snippet where I've configured Auth:

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => false),
            'loginRedirect' => array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'ervaringen', 'action' => 'add'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'ervaringen', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authorize' => array('controller'),
            'flash' => array(
                'element' => 'error',
                'key' => 'auth',
                'params' => array(
                    'heading' => 'Waarschuwing!')
            ),
            'authError' => 'Je moet inloggen om deze inhoud te bekijken.',
        ),
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    );
```

Comment: do you have a beforeFilter function in your `IssueTrackerAppController` file? if so, you have to add another `parent::beforeFilter();` call inside of there

Comment: Yes, there is. Forgot to mention, but that one does a call to `parent::beforeFilter();` as well.

Comment: Can you overwrite component settings using beforeFilter?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Is it a 'Try this', or a 'Can you'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved.

After rescanning all the code in the plugin, I noticed that one of my coworkers on the project used `$variable = $this->requestAction(link/here/with/id/etc);`, which leads towards a controller function. That particular function wasn't allowed in any way by the `beforeFilter()`, causing a 'function denied' bij the `Auth` system.

I've added this particular function in `$this->Auth->allow('function');` in the `beforeFilter()` of the plugin and now it is working.

Comment: That looks like a prime example of using `requestAction` inappropriately - and suffering (some of) the consequences of doing so.

Comment: Yep, I'll start rewriting that bit of code so it'll house in the appropriate model.